# ExpandableListView getting wrong child against group position

Tags: android, json, listview, expandable

I am working with expandablelistview first time, so when i get and set adapter to list the group get whole child items not specific. every group item have all the child items. More over here is my Adapter code . One group item should have its own specific child but group contains all the child items.

**Adapter**

```
public class RestaurantMenuAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<RestaurantParentModel>ListTerbaru;
ArrayList<ArrayList<RestaurantChildModel>> ListChildTerbaru;
int count;

public RestaurantMenuAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<RestaurantParentModel> ListTerbaru, ArrayList<ArrayList<RestaurantChildModel>> ListChildTerbaru){
    this.context=context;
    this.ListTerbaru=ListTerbaru;
    this.ListChildTerbaru=ListChildTerbaru;

}
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return true;
}


@Override
public RestaurantChildModel getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RestaurantChildModel childTerbaru = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    RestaurantMenuAdapter.ViewHolder holder= null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_restaurant_child, null);

        holder=new RestaurantMenuAdapter.ViewHolder();
        holder.title_name_child=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_name_child);
        holder.sub_title_name_child = convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_name_child);
        holder.price_tv = convertView.findViewById(R.id.price_tv);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else{
        holder=(RestaurantMenuAdapter.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title_name_child.setText(childTerbaru.getChild_title());
    holder.sub_title_name_child.setText(childTerbaru.getChild_sub_title());
    holder.price_tv.setText(childTerbaru.getPrice());


    return convertView;
}
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition).size();
}@Override
public RestaurantParentModel getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return ListTerbaru.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return ListTerbaru.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RestaurantParentModel terbaruModel =  getGroup(groupPosition);
    RestaurantMenuAdapter.ViewHolder holder= null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_restaurant_parent, null);

        holder=new RestaurantMenuAdapter.ViewHolder();
        holder.title_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_name);
        holder.sub_title_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_title_name);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }

    else{
        holder=(RestaurantMenuAdapter.ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.title_name.setText(terbaruModel.getTitle());
    holder.sub_title_name.setText(terbaruModel.getSub_title());


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return true;
}


static class ViewHolder{
    TextView title_name,sub_title_name,title_name_child,sub_title_name_child,price_tv;
}
}

 // And how i am calling this adapter from activity is here bellow.




 listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
 listChildData = new ArrayList<>();
 ListChild = new ArrayList<>();
 String id = res_menuItemPref.getString(PreferenceClass.RESTAURANT_ID,"");
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

 try {
     jsonObject.put("id",id);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 JsonObjectRequest resMenuItemRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.SHOW_RESTAURANT_MENU, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


         String strJson =  response.toString();
         JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
         try {
             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(strJson);

             Log.d("JSONPost", jsonResponse.toString());

             int code_id = Integer.parseInt(jsonResponse.optString("code"));

             if (code_id == 200) {

                 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse.toString());
                 JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("msg");

                 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject allJsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject currency = allJsonObject1.getJSONObject("Currency");
                        String currency_symbol = currency.optString("symbol");
                        JSONObject coverImage = allJsonObject1.getJSONObject("Restaurant");
                        String coverImgURL = coverImage.optString("cover_image");
                     Picasso.with(getContext()).load(Config.imgBaseURL+coverImgURL).
                             fit().centerCrop()
                             .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                             .error(R.drawable.unknown_deal).into(cover_image);

                     JSONArray resMenuArray = allJsonObject1.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenu");

                     for (int j =0; j<resMenuArray.length();j++){

                         JSONObject resMenuAllObj = resMenuArray.getJSONObject(j);

                        RestaurantParentModel restaurantParentModel = new RestaurantParentModel();

                        restaurantParentModel.setTitle(resMenuAllObj.optString("name"));
                        restaurantParentModel.setSub_title(resMenuAllObj.optString("description"));

                        listDataHeader.add(restaurantParentModel);


                         JSONArray menuItemArray = resMenuAllObj.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenuItem");
                         for(int k=0;k<menuItemArray.length();k++){
                             JSONObject menuItemArrayObj = menuItemArray.getJSONObject(k);

                             RestaurantChildModel restaurantChildModel = new RestaurantChildModel();

                             restaurantChildModel.setChild_title(menuItemArrayObj.optString("name"));
                             restaurantChildModel.setChild_sub_title(menuItemArrayObj.getString("description"));
                             restaurantChildModel.setPrice(currency_symbol+menuItemArrayObj.optString("price"));

                             listChildData.add(restaurantChildModel);
                             ListChild.add(listChildData);

                         }

                     }

                     restaurantMenuAdapter = new RestaurantMenuAdapter(getContext(), listDataHeader, ListChild);
                     // setting list adapter
                     expandableListView.setAdapter(restaurantMenuAdapter);
                   /*  for(int m=0; m < restaurantMenuAdapter.getGroupCount(); m++)
                         expandableListView.expandGroup(m);*/


                 }

             }
         }
         catch (Exception e){
             e.getMessage();
         }
     }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         Toast.makeText(getContext(),error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 });

 queue.add(resMenuItemRequest);

 }
```

Comment: "One group item should have its own specific child": Does this mean that you only have ONE child per group?

Comment: No That should have multiple specific child child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one,

from main activity, oncreate method,

initiate parent array list only

```
listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
```

then,after complete this line

```
for (int j =0; j<resMenuArray.length();j++){

                     JSONObject resMenuAllObj = resMenuArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    RestaurantParentModel restaurantParentModel = new RestaurantParentModel();

                    restaurantParentModel.setTitle(resMenuAllObj.optString("name"));
                    restaurantParentModel.setSub_title(resMenuAllObj.optString("description"));

                    listDataHeader.add(restaurantParentModel);
```

now initiate child array list

```
listChildData = new ArrayList<>();
```

then,

```
JSONArray menuItemArray = resMenuAllObj.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenuItem");
                     for(int k=0;k<menuItemArray.length();k++){
                         JSONObject menuItemArrayObj = menuItemArray.getJSONObject(k);

                         RestaurantChildModel restaurantChildModel = new RestaurantChildModel();

                         restaurantChildModel.setChild_title(menuItemArrayObj.optString("name"));
                         restaurantChildModel.setChild_sub_title(menuItemArrayObj.getString("description"));
                         restaurantChildModel.setPrice(currency_symbol+menuItemArrayObj.optString("price"));

                         listChildData.add(restaurantChildModel);
                         ListChild.add(listChildData);

                     }

                 }
```

Comment: Yes I choose your approach and it seems some improvements. but now i have 
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
                                                                                    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: I debug my code and the nested for loop not increamenting.

Comment: parent set get class you need to add child set get class. (eg: private ArrayList<Child> child;)    , then  getting child data and before add child to parent array need to add this line (eg: patentArray.sechild(childData);) then add this line ListChild.add(listChildData);

Comment: Ok now I have been solved the Problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to log the entry of your adapter ? 
At first glance, nothing seems to be wrong in your adapter but are you sure the data you want to show to the user arrives as they are supposed to in your adapter?